# automapper Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, automapper

ERROR

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Cities_C391BA93C06F35100522AFBFA8F6BF3823972C9E97D5A49783829A4E90A03F00 -> IEnumerable`1
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Cities_C391BA93C06F35100522AFBFA8F6BF3823972C9E97D5A49783829A4E90A03F00 -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[OsosPlus2.Core.DataAccess.Cities, OsosPlus2.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Destination path:
CustomerViewModel.Cities.Cities

Source value:
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Cities_C391BA93C06F35100522AFBFA8F6BF3823972C9E97D5A49783829A4E90A03F00
```

Action Method:

```
public ActionResult _EditCustomer(int CustomerId)
{
    Customers customer = entity.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.sno == CustomerId);
    CustomerViewModel customerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
    customerViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Customers, CustomerViewModel>(customer);

    customerViewModel.Sectors = entity.Sectors;
    customerViewModel.Cities = entity.Cities;
    customerViewModel.PowerSuppliers = entity.PowerSuppliers;

    return PartialView(customerViewModel);
}
```

When I fetch customer from entity, I get above error. Why only I get this error after fetching?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you want to ignore Cities, Sectors and PowerSuppliers from your mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customers, CustomerViewModel>()
                .ForMember(c => c.Sectors, option => option.Ignore())
                .ForMember(c => c.Cities , option => option.Ignore())
                .ForMember(c => c.PowerSuppliers , option => option.Ignore());
```

I made this assumption since you are setting them manually. Of course you could create mappings for these and automap them as well.