# Automapper + Entity framework : Mapping two entities

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to map two Entities from the same DataContext using automapper, but i'm getting the following **AutoMapperMappingException** :

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
RuntimeType -> Int32
System.RuntimeType -> System.Int32
Destination path:
T_LOGS_RECHERCHE.LOR_I_TYPE.LOR_I_TYPE
Source value:
IndigoSIV2.Core.DAL.T_LOGS
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please post more details of the entities and your automapper setup.

A couple of things spring to mind, ensure that the maps for all dependent objects are defined prior any Mapping.Map<> call.
Remember you will also need maps for any child object properties as automapper traverses the whole object graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the links are there on stackoverflow only:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587824/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

Also it looks like the mapping is in valid so try checking the datatype of elements which are being mapped.