# AutoMapper in MVC3 ViewModel to POCOs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, automapper

I am using EF Code First and defined a number of POCOs. On the other hand, There are some ViewModel classes defined for each of which. Up to here, there are two projects; Model and MVC. Moreover, there is another project containing UnitOfWork and Repository Pattern(a generic repository class).

In the UnitOfWork a number of fields and properties written. Here is an example:

```
public GenericRepository<ActionProvider> ActionProviderRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.actionProviderRepository == null)
            {
                this.actionProviderRepository = new GenericRepository<ActionProvider>(context);
            }
            return actionProviderRepository;
        }
    }
```

The type of this property is that of ActionProvider class defined in the Model project.

**But my problem;** *I need to Map each of the ViewModel to the POCO classes. After surfing the web, I've come to apply AutoMapper*. So the following is what I have done in the UserController class:

```
 public class UserController : Controller
{
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    private User _UserModel = new User();
    private VM_User _VM_User = new VM_User();
    //
    // GET: /User/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        _VM_User = Mapper.Map<MAHAL_E_MA_Model.POCO.User, VM_User>(_UserModel);


        return View(unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(orderBy: us => us.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID)).OfType<User>().ToList());
    }
}
```

And the error is:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I have tried through these links and some other ones but did't work for me!
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677889/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

[And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587824/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping)

Any help would be kindly appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the map somewhere

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MAHAL_E_MA_Model.POCO.User, VM_User>();
```

I have a `Mapping.Setup()` method in `Application_Start` that creates all the maps needed.

Comment: I went through your solution too, but another error came out. `System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectName.POCO.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProjectName.ViewModel.Man.VM_User]'.`  And I also have this code on the View file: `@model IEnumerable<MAHAL_E_MA_Proj.ViewModel.Man.VM_User>`  So, Do you have any idea??

Comment: Are you calling a `ToList` on the `User` collection before passing it to the view?

Comment: As mentioned in the UserController class above(in the question), yes I am. Actually, the Get method is ended with .ToList().

Comment: Basically, as the error says, you're passing it a `List` when it wants an `IEnumerable`. If it's going to get a list every time, you can just change your view to take `@model List<MAHAL_E_MA_Proj.ViewModel.Man.VM_User>`

Comment: Wait, that won't work, sorry, it wants `MAHAL_E_MA_Proj.ViewModel.Man.VM_User` objects and you're passing it `User` objects. You'll have to figure out what you want in the View and pass the correct thing, but this is a different question.

Comment: It makes no difference as I've tested that too. It needs a dictionary of type **VM_User** as I am apparently passing a type of **User**. But have no idea where the latter comes from! Now the error says: **The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectName.POCO.User]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectName.ViewModel.Man.VM_User]'.**

Comment: Shall we have this discussion on chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31263/discussion-between-colm-prunty-and-user2394196)

Comment: Sorry, I am well-Done! I will leave my answer too.. But thanks again your solutions just triggered my mind to overcome the matter :)

Comment: Well, mark me as the answer for the automapper question if I fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I finally overcome the matter by the following lines of code and want to share it perhaps be useful for others:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var query = unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(orderBy: us => us.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID)).OfType<User>().ToList();
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, VM_User>();
        IList<VM_User> vm_Users = Mapper.Map<IList<User>, IList<VM_User>>(query);

        return View(vm_Users);
    }
```