# c# Automapper - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I am trying to map a DTO to a response object, and I keep getting this error because of one child objects of the DTO:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:

Post -> UpdatePostResponse

BingoAPI.Models.Post -> Bingo.Contracts.V1.Responses.Post.UpdatePostResponse

Type Map configuration:

Post -> UpdatePostResponse

BingoAPI.Models.Post -> Bingo.Contracts.V1.Responses.Post.UpdatePostResponse

Destination Member:

Location

 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:

Location -> Location

BingoAPI.Models.Location -> Bingo.Contracts.V1.Responses.Post.Location

   at lambda_method(Closure , Location , Location , ResolutionContext )

   at lambda_method(Closure , Post , UpdatePostResponse , ResolutionContext )

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

This is what I am trying to map:

```
public class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public double? Logitude { get; set; }

        public double? Latitude { get; set; }

        public string? Address { get; set; }

        public string? City { get; set; }

        public string? Region { get; set; }

        public string? Country { get; set; }

        public Post Post { get; set; }

        public int PostId { get; set; }
   }
```

To this **UpdatePostResponse.UpdatedLocation**

```
public class UpdatePostResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Int64 PostTime { get; set; }

        public Int64 EventTime { get; set; }

        public Location Location { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public Event Event { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string>? Pictures { get; set; }

        public List<String>? Tags { get; set; }
    }
    public class UpdatedEvent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class UpdatedLocation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public double? Logitude { get; set; }

        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```

So I am trying to get only the Id, Longitude, Latitude values from Location
This is how I defined the mapping:

```
CreateMap<Models.Location, UpdatedLocation>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Latitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Latitude))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Logitude, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Logitude));

CreateMap<Post, UpdatePostResponse>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Location))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Event, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Event));
```

Also the code for mapping them

```
var ok = new Response<UpdatePostResponse>(mapper.Map<UpdatePostResponse>(mappedPost));
```

I also considered this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587824/automapper-missing-type-map-configuration-or-unsupported-mapping), didn't help

Comment: Can you show us the code that is performing the mapping?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher I updated the post with the code

Comment: The message says you're missing a map, BingoAPI.Models.Location -> Bingo.Contracts.V1.Responses.Post.Location.

Comment: What is your `Post` structure? Which field do you need to map the Post field  in `Location` to `UpdatePostResponse`? As the @kebek in the following post answer, you need to modify your UpdatePostResponse. Similarly for the `Event` class and `Post `class. You first need to clarify which fields in the `Location` map to which fields in `UpdatePostResponse`, then we can to reproduce and try to solve the problem for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a map from `Location` to `UpdatedLocation`,

but in the `UpdatePostResponse` class (to with you are mapping your posts), there is a `Loction` type location property:

```
    public class UpdatePostResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Int64 PostTime { get; set; }
        public Int64 EventTime { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string>? Pictures { get; set; }
        public List<String>? Tags { get; set; }
    }
```

Try the following class definition instead:

```
    public class UpdatePostResponse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Int64 PostTime { get; set; }
        public Int64 EventTime { get; set; }
        public UpdatedLocation Location { get; set; } // notice the type
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string>? Pictures { get; set; }
        public List<String>? Tags { get; set; }
    }
```